# Cannot do inital commit to Git repository

Tags: git, windows-7-x64

I navigate to a directory i want to make a new git repository in.
I run the following code:

```
git init
touch readme
git add --all
git commit -m "test commit"
```

and i get the following error:

```
error: unable to find e80ad49ace82167de62e498622d70377d913c79e
fatal: e80ad49ace82167de62e498622d70377d913c79e is not a valid object
```

Anyone have any ideas? Everything in the .git folder seems to be correct. It has a HEAD file.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, if you're creating a brand new Git repository, it shouldn't have a HEAD file since you've no commits yet. Perhaps try deleting the `.git` folder a try again?

Comment: When i just run git init, a HEAD file is created by default. I have tried this about a dozen times already. Disbelieving that such a simple thing would not work...

Comment: @miqid I can confirm that a HEAD file is created regardless of # of commits. However, I cannot reproduce the OP's issue (I just ran the same exact 4 commands you posted, and everything went through fine).

Comment: Ah, disregard my comment, I meant to say that the file HEAD references under `.git/refs/heads` (i.e. master) shouldn't get created until you commit.